# Trying to WP_Query a category

Tags: categories, wp-query

I am trying to output all the posts of a certain category but all that is happening is The page content is being outputted no posts?

template page

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">

                    <div id="main" class="eightcol first clearfix" role="main">



                   <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=blog' ); ?> 


                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                            <header class="article-header">

                                <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                  <p class="byline vcard"><?php
                    printf(__('Posted <time class="updated" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time> by <span class="author">%3$s</span>.', 'bonestheme'), get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', 'bonestheme')), bones_get_the_author_posts_link());
                  ?></p>


                            </header> <!-- end article header -->

                            <section class="entry-content">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section> <!-- end article section -->

                            <footer class="article-footer">
                                <p class="clearfix"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags">' . __('Tags:', 'bonestheme') . '</span> ', ', ', ''); ?></p>

                            </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                            <?php comments_template(); ?>

                        </article> <!-- end article -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>  

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry clearfix">
                                <header class="article-header">
                                    <h1><?php _e("Oops, Post Not Found!", "bonestheme"); ?></h1>
                                </header>
                                <section class="entry-content">
                                    <p><?php _e("Uh Oh. Something is missing. Try double checking things.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
                                </section>
                                <footer class="article-footer">
                                    <p><?php _e("This is the error message in the page-custom.php template.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
                                </footer>
                            </article>

                        <?php endif; ?>


                    </div> <!-- end #main -->

                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

                </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->

            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You're using WP_Query incorrectly. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WP_Query incorrectly: you need to be calling the `have_posts()` and `the_post()` functions as methods of your `$query` variable:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

You should also call `wp_reset_postdata();` after the query loop is finished.

Learn more about how to use the WP_Query class at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage).